# Apache FTPClient for Java show FTP Commands that were run

Tags: java, apache, ftp, client

Hello I am using Apache Commons FTP Client and I want to show the FTP Commands that the FTP Client uses so like when I use changeWorkingDirectory it should show me the FTP Command that it used like: CODEOFCOMMAND CHD .....

or when I upload a File it should show me: CODEOFCOMMAND PUT ....

Is there any possibility to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find it in the [Apache Commons Net FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Net/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) :

Q: How do I debug FTP applications?

A: You can add a protocol command listener; for example:

```
ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));
```

Comment: Yes i already found that but Ill accept the answer cause I also did it like that :)

Answer (score 0):

**-** Its **one of the most important aspect** of `Object Oriented Programming` to **hide the implementation** from the implementer (In this case the Programmer).

**-** And as you are using `Apache's commons library` for the `ftp`, you are permitted to use the functionality, were as the implementation is hidden.

Comment: Good point. But for debugging, it might be usefull to see the implementation. In Hibernate you can log the generated SQL code also.

Answer (score 0):

Here for the people that also need it:

First do:

```
redirectSystemStreams();
ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));
```

but because I am using a JTextArea in a GUI and I need the output there I hat to redirect the output I did it by creating these Methods (Replace txtLog with your TextArea):

```
private void updateTextArea(final String text) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                txtLog.append(text);
            }
        });
    }

    private void redirectSystemStreams() {
        OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
                write(b, 0, b.length);
            }
        };

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
    }
```